How to downgrade loki version
Currently I am using Grafana version 8.1.2 which is using loki verison - github.com/grafana/loki v1.6.2-0.20210520072447-15d417efe103
but I want to downgrade the loki version to github.com/grafana/loki v1.6.2-0.20201026154740-6978ee5d7387 which is being used in 7.5.17.
How to achieve it?
Any suggestions?
I tried to replace the loki version in go.mod file of 8.1.2 with the one being used in 7.5.17. But it breaks the Grafana server.
